# Map with annotations pins like Foursquare, swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, foursquare

I am working on an app based on the **Map View**, and I wanted to implement something like **Foursquare** : in front of the map that you can scroll and that is linked with the pins.
I tried with the Collection View but without success.. Does anyone know how to do it or have an idea?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding UICollectionView above MapView (use addSubview method or add in storyboard) and set background color of collection view to UIColor.clearColor. By this the collection view cell will look floating above the map view.

Comment: thanks I'm going to try, I will give you feedback as soon as possible!

Comment: I got it, thanks again. I have the data as well on the map as on the collection view. Nevertheless, when I select one of the pins, I fail to show the good cell of the collection view and to change the pin color at the same time.. Do you have an idea of how to do it please?

Comment: Whenever you selected the pin, you can get the indexPath of the pin and call this method `scrollToItemAtIndexPath(_:atScrollPosition:animated:)`. The collection view will scroll to the target cell base on indexpath.

Comment: Thank you! I am finishing my upload with Parse and I am going to try!